# Using comparison theorem

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

So I think I have a grasp on this theorem: If a function *f* that is greater than another function *g*, and *f* is convergent, then *g* must also be convergent, and vice versa with divergence: if *f* is less than *g* and *f* is divergent, then *g* is also divergent.

That makes sense, but im having trouble applying this theorem to this integral:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{|sin(x)| + {e}^{-x}}{x^2}dx$$

Ive tried going the route:

$$\frac{|sin(x)| + {e}^{-x}}{x^2} = \frac{e^x|sin(x)| + 1}{x^2e^x} > \frac{|sin(x)|}{x^2} > \frac{sin(x)}{x^2}$$

But I get stuck when I try to find $\int^\infty_1\frac{sin(x)}{x^2}dx$

Answer (score 1):

- $|\sin x| \leq 1$ for $x \in [1,\infty)$.
- $\mathrm{e}^{-x} \leq 1$ for $x \in [1, \infty)$.  (In fact, $\mathrm{e}^{-x} \leq 1/\mathrm{e}$ on this interval, but we don't need tight bounds.)
- So compare with $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \; \frac{2}{x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to solve this problem is to note that$$x\geqslant1\implies\lvert\sin x\rvert+e^{-x}<2$$and to use the fact that the integral$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$converges.